How do I disable Git Credential Manager while deploy apps through Intune

I noticed that in the latest version of Git, the default is now to pop up a "Git Credential Manager enabled by default. how can we disable the Git credential Manager to make None while we deploy apps through Intune? Basically use the below command to deploy
Install Coomand # Git-2.44.0-64-bit.exe /VERYSILENT /NORESTART
Uninstall Command # "%ProgramFiles%\Git\unins000.exe" /VERYSILENT /NORESTART

if there is any other install command we can include it while deploying apps through Intune. so the Git credential manager command can be disabled. (like none).
